# Login to GCE instance without ssh

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a server where I had installed a drive. I removed the drive but forgot to remove the entry from /etc/fstab. Now, the instance would not boot and I cannot get ssh access. IS there a way to fix the machine? All I need to do is to remove one entry from /etc/fstab and restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before starting the process I would recommend taking a [snapshot](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2013/10/persistent-disk-backups-using-snapshots.html) of the disk. In order to modify the fstab on the affected disk, you need to do the following:

1. Delete the instance without deleting the disk.
2. Create a brand new instance where you can ssh
3. Attach the affected disk to it as a secondary disk
4. Ssh into the instance, mount the disk if it's not already mounted,  and modify the changes.
5. Detach the modified disk and create a new instance using this disk as a primary root disk.